# RequireNonLetterOrDigit not correctly validated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I created a password validator as follows:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 8,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false, 
    RequireDigit = false,
    RequireLowercase = true,
    RequireUppercase = true,
};
```

But, a password such as Testing123 is considered invalid:

> Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character.

The error message is pretty unclear, it says that the password should have at least one non letter *or* digit character. Well, I have 3 digits. So what's wrong then? When I add an non letter

Comment: Did you mean RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both the name and [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordvalidator.requirenonletterordigit(v=vs.108).aspx) of this property are ambiguous. This should be:

> Gets or sets whether the password requires a character that is not a
>   letter and not a digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class CustomPasswordValidator : PasswordValidator
{
    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(string password)
    {
        var requireNonLetterOrDigit = base.RequireNonLetterOrDigit;
        base.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
        var result = await base.ValidateAsync(password);

        if (!requireNonLetterOrDigit)
            return result;

        if (!Enumerable.All<char>((IEnumerable<char>)password, new Func<char, bool>(this.IsLetterOrDigit)))
            return result;

        // Build a new list of errors so that the custom 'PasswordRequireNonLetterOrDigit' could be added. 
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            list.Add(error);
        }
        // Add our own message: (The default by MS is: 'Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character.')
        list.Add("Passwords must have at least one character that is neither a letter or digit. (E.g. '£ $ % ^ _ etc.')");
        result = await Task.FromResult<IdentityResult>(IdentityResult.Failed(string.Join(" ", (IEnumerable<string>)list)));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful